# Depois de compilar e rodar, o algoritmo mostra "excesso de ponto flutuante gravado", por que?

Tags: c, matemática

Algoritmo para descobrir se um número é primo, dando o erro de excesso de ponto flutuante.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

int n, i, divisivel;
divisivel =0;

printf("Digite um numero para saber se eh primo: \n");
scanf("%d", &n);

for(i = n; i >= 0; i--){
        if(n%i == 0){
            divisivel =divisivel + 1;
        }


}

if(divisivel <=2){
    printf("o numero %i eh primo!: \n", n);

}else{
    printf("o numero %i não eh primo \n", n);
}
return (0);
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

O erro aí é que está dando divisão por 0 já que a condição do `for` deixar ir até 0, então deveria comparar só se é maior que zero e não se é igual. Na verdade não tem porque comprar se a divisão por 1 dá certo, todos os números dão. Simplificando o código ficaria assim:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Digite um numero para saber se eh primo: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int divisivel = 0;
    for (int i = n; i > 1; i--) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            divisivel++;
            if (divisivel == 2) {
                printf("o numero %i não eh primo \n", n);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("o numero %i eh primo \n", n);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fm4FIA). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Primec). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Prime.c).

Na verdade o código pode ser otimizado usando raiz quadrada, pesquise sobre isto..

Comment: Valeu, cara, me ajudou bastante. Estou aprendendo a programar agora, entao tem muitos detalhes q ainda não sei. Obrigado mesmo

Comment: @mitobk6 veja no [tour/ a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.